# How implement idea plugin top tips java implements?

Tags: plugins, tooltip

How implement red block by java?
This is idea plugin,URL:
[https://github.com/gejun123456/EasyCodeMybatisCodeHelperTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWIZ9.png)
thanks you help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NUF.png)

`Editor editor = event.getDataContext().getData(PlatformDataKeys.EDITOR); editor.get..add....show`